# jQuery count of child elements returning 0?

Tags: jquery, dom

Simple code, not sure why it isn't working. I'm trying to count the number of immediate child elements within a div, and I am not having much success:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li class="page1 active" data-index="1"><a href="#1"></a></li>
    <li class="page2" data-index="2"><a href="#2"></a></li>
    <li class="page3" data-index="3"><a href="#3"></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="main">
        <section class="page1 active" data-index="1">Scroll 1</section>
        <section class="page2" data-index="2">Scroll 2</section>
        <section class="page3" data-index="3">Scroll 3</section>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

When I `console.log` this code however:

```
console.log($('div.main').children('section').length);
```

I get a result of 0, when it should be 3. Why is this? I'm running FF25 and jQ 1.9.1, if that helps.

Comment: on chrome & FF  it works fine !!

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/GQbVZ/); are you wrapping the code in a `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */})` (or equivalent)? Does the DOM exist when the script is encountered by the browser?

Comment: @DavidThomas Ahh, stupid me. Of course I wasn't! Thanks.

Comment: @Antilogical: thanks for marking as solved, though on Stack Overflow there's a better way to do this. To mark a question as done, simply ask the answerer to post the answer, and accept it using the tick icon. For simple solutions such as this one, you may as well do it yourself, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Trying this myself, it comes up with 3.  On JSBin: http://jsbin.com/iBIBaLi/1/edit